# Different worksheet, same value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to click on a button which will take me to a different worksheet cell where the value of this cell is the same as the value of one cell in the original worksheet.

Worksheet 1:

[image]

Worksheet 2:

[image]

When I click the blue button on WS1, the value of c1 should be saved, and then go to WS2 cell where the value is the same as c1 in ws1. In this case, it should take me to A1.

Comment: Why not just hyperlink it?

Comment: considering that c1 is a "dynamic" cell, hyperlinking it wouldn't help me, i think. let's say that c1 changes to mexico, it should redirect to A5 on WS2 when i click on the button.

Comment: You're going to have to write a dynamic routine anyway. Just write a dynamic hyperlink one.

Comment: found this >> http://trumpexcel.com/2014/03/create-dynamic-hyperlinks-in-excel/

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Sub Find()
AA = Selection.Value

Sheets("WS2").Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=AA, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```